# Decay speed of positive random uniforms

Tags: limits, random-variables, uniform-distribution, products

I'm trying to quantify

1. for what values of $\theta$ and
2. at what speed

a product $Y$ of $n$ independent uniform random variables $x_i$ between zero and $\theta$, decays to zero. That is $$Y=\prod_1^n x_i, \quad x_i\sim U[0,\theta].$$  Empirically it seems that the tipping point from convergence to zero and divergence is somewhere around $\theta=2.75$ but I am having a hard time finding out why. Obviously, the smaller $\tau$ the faster the deday. But I also wonder how fast exactly (say in expectation).

Thanks a lot in advance :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the $x_i$ are independent.  Then $\mathbb E[Y_n] = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[x_i] = (\theta/2)^n$, so the threshold for expected value $\to 0$ is at $\theta = 2$.
But if you want an "almost surely" result, use logarithms to turn the product into a sum,
where you can use the Laws of Large Numbers.
$$ \ln(Y_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x_i)$$
Now $\mathbb E[\ln(x_i)] = \ln(\theta)-1$.  The Strong Law of Large Numbers says that with probability $1$, $\ln(Y_n)/n \to \ln(\theta) - 1$ as $n \to \infty$.  In particular, if
$\ln(\theta) < 1$, i.e. $\theta < e$, this implies $\ln(Y_n) \to -\infty$ i.e. $Y_n \to 0$, while if $\theta > e$ it implies $Y_n \to \infty$.

Comment: Dear Robert! Thanks a lot for your fast and elaborate answer. $x_i$ are independent indeed. Please allow me a follow-up question: I had actually started from $(\theta/2)^n$ myself but in my simulations this quickly becomes a lose upper bound. Your second suggestion matches my results much more closely but sometimes it actually overestimates the decay speed, i.e. $\bar{Y}_n>e^{n (ln(\theta)-1)}$ for all $n=1,...,300$ (for example) and when taking the average of multiple independent runs ($\bar{Y}=1/m \sum_j Y_{j,n}$). Am I making some mistake?

Comment: Regarding the (first) expectation argument, as you say for $\theta=2$ one would expect no decay at all but I still almost always observe that. I'm guessing the variance is somehow increasing in $n$ and thus rendering the expectation a bad estimator?

Comment: What's happening, essentially, is that $Y_n$ is usually near $\exp(n (\ln(\theta)-1))$ (as implied by the Law of Large Numbers) but sometimes it is much larger (as implied by the expected value).  If you average over $m$ runs, you're more likely to see some of these large values, so the numbers will tend to be greater than $\exp(n (\ln(\theta)-1))$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the explanation. For finite n, it is not correct that $Y_n$ is $exp(n(ln(\theta)-1))$ with probability 1, is it? If not, is there some way to quantify or bound the probability? Or to derive a meaningful upper bound on $Y_n$ that holds with $p=1$? (Does something equivalent to concentration bounds from sums of random variables exist for products?)